# jabber-net chat conversation

Tags: c#, chat, xmpp

I'm making simple XMPP client using Jabber-Net. To send simple message i'm using a way from example code, i.e.:

```
jabber.protocol.client.Message msg = new jabber.protocol.client.Message(jc.Document);
msg.To = "adress@jabber.com";
msg.Body = "hello world";
jc.Write(msg);
```

it works fine, but I would like to send **chat message**.
I mean that in PSI (http://psi-im.org/) i can send to somebody simple message or talk to him on chat (its another kind of form for that). How can it be done in jabber-net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
msg.Type = jabber.protocol.client.MessageType.Chat;
```